# How to get the execution time(time to get response) of rest api in spring or using junit

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mocking, easymock

I want to save the execution time of rest api. The is same as what we can see in postman next to status.
Is there any way in Junit?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it manually.

example:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
Response response = server.newRequest("/requesturl").request().buildPost(Entity.text("45")).invoke();
long responseTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
save(responseTime);
```

Or if you want to test the response time then look [here](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2015/12/28/rest-assured-how-to-check-response-times/)

Comment: It is right. And the link given is very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The manual way is indeed pretty easy. Especially with Java 8 where you can do

```
private void timed(Runnable r) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    r.run();
    long responseTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
    save(responseTime);
}
```

In JUnit you have the Stopwatch rule that allow you to have test execution calculated.

Codahale also have a `@Timed` annotation with a result that can be send to a collector. But there's a bit more wiring needed to make it all work.